# Oracle MAF iOS app rejected by Apple - IPV6 network compatible issue

Tags: java, ios, web-services, ipv6, oracle-maf

I have developed an Oracle MAF iOS Mobile app and its failed calling web service when network is IPV6 compatible.

I have used below code for web service calling -

```
String restPayload = "";

RestServiceAdapter restServiceAdapter = Model.createRestServiceAdapter();
restServiceAdapter.clearRequestProperties();
restServiceAdapter.setConnectionName("PortPassConn");

//set GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
restServiceAdapter.setRequestType(httpMethod);

restServiceAdapter.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

restServiceAdapter.setRequestURI(requestURI);        
restServiceAdapter.setRetryLimit(0);    

//variable holding the response
String response = "";

//set payload if there is payload passed with the request
if(payload != null){   
     //send with empty payload
     restPayload  = payload;
}

try {
    response = (String) restServiceAdapter.send(restPayload);

} catch (Exception e) {

    MessageUtils.handleError("We encounter server side error, "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
    //We encounter server side error, with http status code - 
    //log error
  //  Trace.log("REST_JSON",Level.SEVERE, this.getClass(),"invokeRestRequest", "Invoke of REST Resource failed for "+httpMethod+" to "+requestURI);
   // Trace.log("REST_JSON",Level.SEVERE, this.getClass(),"invokeRestRequest", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Getting error as:

> "We encounter server side error, Network is unreachable."

Comment: What is the `requestURI` that you are trying to call?